# XNA - Attempting to load textures in another class always gives GraphicsDevice component not found

Tags: c#, xna, textures, texture2d

I have read many different solutions to problems similar to this but I cannot find a solution that works for me.

I am just starting on making a simple game to learn the basics of XNA, but I cannot get textures to load in an additional class. I tried this:

EDIT: This is not the main class incase I didn't make that clear enough

```
class Wizard
{
    // Variables
    Texture2D wizardTexture;
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics; // I added this line in later, but it didn't seem to do anything

    public Wizard(ContentManager content, GraphicsDeviceManager graphics)
    {
        this.graphics = graphics;
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        LoadContent();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        wizardTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Wizard"); // Error is here
        base.LoadContent();
    }
```

I have also tried making a method like

```
public Texture2D Load(ContentManager Content)
{
     return Content.Load<Texture2D>("Wizard");
}
```

And then have wizardTexture = Load(Content); but that did not work either.

Any help and an explanation is appreciated, thanks

Comment: i don't have any of my XNA Games here at work. but if you can wait about 6 hours, I will be home from work and be able to look at some of my games that I need to start up again. I believe I battled the same issue.

Comment: How is the `GraphicsDeviceManager` created? In the Windows Game template provided with XNA Game Studio, the `GraphicsDeviceManager` is created inside your Game's constructor like so: `graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);`.  Fyi, you should only have 1 class that extends `Game`, and it's usually easiest to start with one of the templates provided with the tool.

Comment: I can't remember clearly but I believe I had better luck passing the game instance and storing that off to get the graphisDeviceManager than doing what you were doing. I don't have an explanation as to why this is the case though

Comment: @ToddersLegrande How can I pass the game instance through to other classes?

Comment: @JeromeShah - the edit of Blau's post is more or less what I was talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the usual constructor for an xna game... it seems that you are using a hack to let using the game class in a winform... if you want to use that way... you are passing wrong the parameteres or your not creating right the graphicsdevicemanager

The usual way to create a xna game is defining this two files:

```
 // program.cs file
 static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Game1 game = new Game1())
            {
                game.Run();
            }
        }
    }


 // Game1.cs file
 public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game {
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

    public Game1( ) {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager( this );
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }
    ....
 }
```

You should realize that the game constructor has no parameters, and the graphicsdevicemanager its created inside the constructor

**EDIT: I was thinking that maybe your wizard class its not intended to be a game, but a GameComponent or DrawableGameComponent, in this case it should be:**

```
class Wizard : DrawableGameComponent {
    Texture2D wizardTexture;

    public Wizard(Game game) : base(game)
    {
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
       wizardTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Wizard"); // Error is here
        base.LoadContent();
    }
    ....
}
```

Then in you main game class when you initialize the object... you can add add it to the Components collection.

```
 class Game1: Game {
    ....
    public override void Initialize() {

        Components.Add( new Wizard(this));
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Works in this way

```
texture = Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>(textureName);
```